# CpuTime in Java. How does it correspond with real CPU cycles?

Tags: java

as above: What exactly `bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime( )` returns ? What CpuTime is?

Comment: Probably amount of time spent in the ["Running" state](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html).  Without more information, you couldn't figure real CPU cycles.  That would change every machine you run on and the state of the machine at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are searching for : [How to get CPU time ?](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking)

> From the [**Wiki's**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time),  CPU time (or
> CPU usage, process time) is the amount
> of time for which a central processing
> unit (CPU) was used for processing
> instructions of a computer program, as
> opposed to, for example, waiting for
> input/output operations.

The amount of time the CPU is actually executing instructions. During the execution of most programs, the CPU sits idle much of the time while the computer fetches data from the keyboard or disk, or sends data to an output device. The CPU time of an executing program, therefore, is generally much less than the total execution time of the program. Multitasking operating systems take advantage of this by sharing the CPU among several programs.

See here :  [bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime( )](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=ed943f71b5463e3dec7664b82f883?bug_id=6175366)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

"Returns the total CPU time for the current thread in nanoseconds."

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html

Comment: I have seen this, but what CPU time is? How is it measured?